# Distribute the file to all connected clients

Tags: c#

I have a UDP server. Which distributes a patch file of the game, to anyone who requires it. But I ran into a problem: I can't correctly send a file that weighs 126 MB. I made a crutch program. I create a MemoryStream and send 8192 bytes to the client. It seems to me that this is the wrong decision. How can it be be made easier?

Comment: Simplest thing to do here, is upload the file to a web server and let the client make a request to download the file, I don't know why you are making it harder for yourself and doing it via a memory stream and using udp. You could also provide some code to maybe help fix your current solution. TL:DR upload to web, check on clientside if the patch is needed, if yes, do a request to download and apply the patch.

Comment: Can you please tell me which service you can use? When I do a client update. I wrote a program that patches all versions of patches. And updates their data. It would be convenient to upload all these versions to the portal, and have access to them through the "WebClient" class. I can work with him. The Google Drive service did not help in solving this issue. Maybe there is some simple example?

Answer (score 0):

There are zero advantages of using UDP once you implement packets ordering and transmission errors retransmit. If you just use TCP, it will be as fast and without issues.